# Footer glitch when browser window is not wide enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, footer

See image for example.  This happens in IE8 and Opera 10.62 (I didn't test other browsers).  Basically, if your browser window is not wide enough, the footer is a bit broken when you scroll.

[image]

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 6.0.472

Comment: Reproduced in Opera 10.62 build 6438 on Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit.

Comment: After playing around with the CSS files... I still can't determine why that's happening. Time to fire up jsFiddle, I guess.

Comment: I found the problem!

Comment: Repro in FF 3.6.10 as well. Nice find.

Comment: Am I missing something? Nothing seems to have changed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the following solution instead of [George's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66074/footer-glitch-when-browser-window-is-not-wide-enough/66075#66075):

```
#footer {
/* Current styles */
min-width:960px;
}
```

This preserves the current behavior of the footer stretching page wide while still fixing the bug.

Comment: Good job. Although I intended for the footer to just be centered, this looks much nicer.

Comment: +1: Not only does this look nicer, it also properly matches the existing behavior when the window is expanded.  Very easy to implement, too.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the problem and the solution.

**The problem:**

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footerwrap">
    ...
```

**The solution:**

```
<div id="footer" style="width: 960px;">
    <div class="footerwrap">
    ...
```

Notice the addition of `style="width: 960px;"`.

This forces the bottom bar to be the same width as the rest of the page.

---

**Update:** It is also necessary to include:

```
margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;
```

in the style parameter. This centers the bar along the bottom.

Comment: This breaks the footer (a different way) once you make your browser window wide again.

Comment: @wai: No it doesn't. Read my update at the bottom.

Comment: Right, it centers the footer, but the background doesn't extend all the way to the left and right.

Comment: @wai: That's not a glitch - I intended that to happen.